# Unable to subscribe to Google Drive push notifications

Tags: google-drive-api

Based on:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

I do not understand where to get the `auth_token_for_current_user` from.

I have service account credentials, also an OAuth token. I have tried the `access_token`, `refresh_token`... I do not understand what token this is supposed to be.

```
  curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 1//064ToBH1n***' \
--data-raw '{ 
    "id":"***", 
    "type": "web_hook", 
    "address": "https://***.cloudfunctions.net/verify" 
}'
```

returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Authorization header should contain a valid access token.